# Why does Lightbox extend my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I apologise if this question is worded poorly, but I have only recently begun working with CSS and Javascript and so I'm a bit lost in some places!

I'm making a portfolio website right now, and I'd like to use lightbox to showcase some of my pieces. However, it's not working the way I've seen it work on other sites - when I click on the link, while the image comes up alright, it also extends the page, the black overlay in the background doesn't go all the way down, and the loading gif and the close, previous, and next buttons all seem to be shifted a little to the right.

I believe it has to do with inherited styles (and my own not-so-great CSS), and I've tried inspecting the element but cannot find where it's affecting the lightbox CSS. I've also tried moving the lightbox links outside of where my CSS should affect it, but it happens there anyway.

If anyone could explain to me why this happens, and how to avoid in the future, I'd be much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style.css remove the `div {...}` part, as it affects all `div`s and declare more specific CSS styles. In CSS you should generally make CSS styles as specific as possible.

Comment: Ahhh, alright, I'll keep that in mind! But in this case, for this page, I only ever use div once; would it affect it that much? Should I be cutting up my divs into chunks?

Comment: Most stuff on the web is constructed out of divs, they are the "standards-blocks" and the lightbox is made out of them too

Comment: But did it solve the problem?

Comment: It solved most of it! The images are now all in the right place, and the page no longer extends, but the black overlay doesn't cover all of the window. **only in some window-sizes, though; in other window-sizes it works just fine

Comment: Maybe try to add min-height:100%; to body

Comment: it doesn't seem to work - it's only for incredibly small windows that it does that, anyhow! I think it's because the image ends up being larger than the page itself? at any rate, thank you so very much for your help so far!

Comment: Fo small displays add max-width and max-height to .lb-image (.lb-image {max-width:100%;max-height:400px;} for example)